# Magento 2 Certified Front End Developer exam reading material

Tags: magento2, frontend, certification

We know Magento recently released [Magento 2 Certified Front End Developer](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-front-end-developer) exam.

I know the passing score is 63%, but I want to know what study material is useful in this exam (apart from free study guide from Magento)

Number of questions going to ask in exam?

Number of retake for that exam?

Are there any passing criteria for `EE edition` just like we have in `M1 Developer Plus Exam` ?

How many free retakes are available (If you fail in first attempt)?

Answer (score 2):

**After acquiring Magento by Adobe:** Complete Guide

**Study Material Guide :** Check below

[AD0-E701: Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/14TT3gvQkRV5Q/)

- Exam number: AD0-E701
- Certificate level: Certified Expert
- Available languages: English, Japanese
- Number of questions: 60
- Formats: Multiple choice
- Duration: 120 minutes
- Delivery: Onsite/Online proctored (requires camera access) or test center proctored
- Passing mark: 63%
- Price: $295 USD

For more information [here](https://spark.adobe.com/page/14TT3gvQkRV5Q/)

Have Question in mind check  FAQ Section [here](https://learning.adobe.com/products-resources/faq.html#cert-general)

Comment: Just to add, I emailed magento and they will offer a 20% discount if you do not pass the exam.

Answer (score 0):

As Adobe change Certification Name and code, for latest update For The frontend Certification please visit this link. https://spark.adobe.com/page/14TT3gvQkRV5Q/

For All other Certification visit here : https://learning.adobe.com/certification.html